# Insert multiple select values with ajax and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Im trying to insert my multiple select values to my database. I've tried using multiple ways to add but i can't get it to work. I'm passing the selected values in a hidden textbox (in this example is not hidden). Here is part of the code:

The select:

---

```
<select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" id="services" style="height: 36px;width: 100%; border: 1px solid #ccc;">
  <?php
  $services = get_all_services();
  foreach ($services as $s) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo safe_output($s["service_id"]); ?>"><?php echo safe_output($s["service_name"]); ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>

<input type="text" name="hidden_service" id="hidden_service" />
```

---

Ajax code

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var services = $('#hidden_service').val($('#services').val());

    
    $.ajax({
      url: 'auths/add-dealers.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
       services:services
       
      }, success: function(data){
        $("#result").html(data);
      }

    })

    $("#form")[0].reset();
});
```

---

Insert Method:

```
if(isset($_POST['hidden_service'])){
  $services = safe_input($_POST['hidden_service']);

  $sql="INSERT INTO " . TBL_DEALER_SERVICES . "(`dealer_id`, `service_id`) VALUES (:dealer, :services)";

  $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);

  $stmt->execute(array(
    ':dealer'       =>  $lastDealer,
    ':services'     =>  $_POST['hidden_service']
  ));
}
```

Comment: You're missing the `:` before `dealer` and `services` in `$sql`.

Comment: `VALUES (:dealer, :services)`

Comment: Also, you can't use `fetchAll()` with `INSERT` queries, only `SELECT`.

Comment: You should have gotten an error -- make sure you have `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` enabled.

Comment: Fixed, but it still doesnt' work

Comment: What is the datatype of `service_id`?

Comment: In the db is INT

Comment: But `hidden_service` is a comma-delimited string. How do you expect to store that in an integer column?

Comment: You're not setting the variable `services` to the value of the input. You're setting it to the jQuery object containing the hidden input element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for the hidden input. Send the array of values in the AJAX request.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'auths/add-dealers.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
       services: $("#services").val()
      }, success: function(data){
        $("#result").html(data);
      }

    })

    $("#form")[0].reset();
});
```

Then in PHP, you need to loop over the array, inserting each value into a different row of the table.

```
if(isset($_POST['services'])){
    $sql="INSERT INTO " . TBL_DEALER_SERVICES . "(`dealer_id`, `service_id`) VALUES (:dealer, :services)";
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($_POST['services'] as $service) {
        $stmt->execute(array(
                           ':dealer'       =>  $lastDealer,
                           ':services'     =>  $service
                           ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually helped me. Totally forgot about the foreach. Thanks a lot.